# UIEvent has timestamp. How can I generate an equivalent value on my own?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

According to the cocoa documentation, `timestamp` on `UIEvent` is "the number of seconds since system startup." It's an `NSTimeInterval`.

I'd like to generate, as efficiently as possible, an equivalent number. Of course, *I* want to do this where `UIEvent` don't shine. :-)

Comment: (To be clear, for my app I plan to hold on to `timestamp` values from `UIEvent` objects _as well as_ my own generated `timestamp` values, and I want the ordering of these values to make sense. So I expect the `timestamp` values I generate to be meaningfully comparable with those from `UIEvent`.)

Comment: Your solution in http://stackoverflow.com/a/2406018/1091780 works fine, but the code gets very hard to debug. The timestamp function does not seem to stop the time increments, and I guess that's expected. Did you experience the same problem? I would have written this as a comment if I had more reputation points :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, I did a little digging and here is what I came up with:

```
#import <mach/mach.h>
#import <mach/mach_time.h>

+ (NSTimeInterval)timestamp
{
    // get the timebase info -- different on phone and OSX
    mach_timebase_info_data_t info;
    mach_timebase_info(&info);

    // get the time
    uint64_t absTime = mach_absolute_time();

    // apply the timebase info
    absTime *= info.numer;
    absTime /= info.denom;

    // convert nanoseconds into seconds and return
    return (NSTimeInterval) ((double) absTime / 1000000000.0);
}
```

This appears to be equivalent to `timestamp` from `UIEvent`, which given what `mach_absolute_time()` does makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Does `AbsoluteToNanoseconds` exist on the iPhone? If so, it'd be easier to use that than the timebase info. If not, I'd suggest dividing the numerator by the denominator (after casting one of them to `NSTimeInterval`) and multiplying by that fraction.

Comment: Isn't AbsoluteToNanoseconds a Carbon API? I hadn't considered using it... not sure about its availability on the phone.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could combine the `NSDate` method [`-timeIntervalSinceDate:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/timeIntervalSinceDate:) and the `mach` framework-based function [`GetPIDTimeInNanoseconds`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2004/qa1398.html) to get to the same result.

Comment: I looked at `GetPIDTimeInNanoseconds` and realized that `mach_absolute_time()` was the place to be. So I wrote the blob of code in my answer above. Thanks.